# Joomla - How can I locate Administrator Module to different page other than main Administrator page?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am new to Joomla. I have to add an administrator module to the page where a specific module is being edited at administrator side. 
For example here is the module editing page where I want to add an Administrator module
[image: specific Module editing page]

But there isn't any option for `menu assignment` in administrator module editing page. It always shows on front administrator page

[image: Admin module editing page]

**Here is XML file**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <extension type="module" version="3.1" client="administrator" method="upgrade">
  <name>mod_admincustom</name>
  <author>Your Name Goes Here</author>
  <creationDate>December 2015</creationDate>
  <copyright>Copyright (C) 2015 Your Brand Goes Here</copyright>
  <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
  <authorEmail>email@nomail.com</authorEmail>
  <authorUrl>www.yoursite.any</authorUrl>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <description>Custom Module for Administrator</description>
  <files>
      <filename module="mod_admincustom">mod_admincustom.php</filename>
  </files>
  </extension>
```

Can you please specify that what kind of changes can I do to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only show modules on the front page of admin section (Control Panel).

If you want to show your module on a specific view of a component, you can create a template override for that view and load the module manually.

Another option is cloning the default template of admin, then you can customize the new template and load any modules any where.